# How to get a collection of sales_order_status_history models with a specific set of id's for parent_id column?

Tags: magento2, collection

Magento 2 has order status history inside each order which essentially is just comments related to a order. All of them are stored in one single database table sales_order_status_history. Each comment relates to order by value in column `parent_id` which maps to `order_id`. I have a set of order id's in an array.
My end goal is to get an array or a collection with comments related to those orders with single query to make it more efficient. I don't want to write direct database queries. I want to utilize collections functionality that I believe allows you to do something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$ids` is an array, the collection would need to be filtered like this:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', array('in' => $ids));
```

This will allow you to filter by an array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think the missing part was the fact that second argument has to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to add a method into a class that should retrieve the comment collection.
You need to add this to your class :

```
protected $historyCollectionFactory;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\History\CollectionFactory $historyCollectionFactory,
    ....
)
{
    ....
    $this->historyCollectionFactory = $historyCollectionFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then create the method that retrieves the items:

```
public function getStatusHistoryItems($ids)
{
    $collection = $this->historyCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $ids);
    //additional collection changes here, if needed.
    return $collection;
}
```